# Angular: Reading State from a Component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

What's the correct way to read state from within a component? I've got a navigation component that is visible across my app, and I'm trying to add class of `active` to an `<li>` element when you're on the page that corresponds to the item in the navigation.

Is it best to pass the state down to it like so:

**index.html**

```
<nav state-name="$state.current.name"></nav>
```

**nav.component.js**

```
export default class Nav {
  template = `<ul>
                <li ng-class="{ 'active': $ctrl.currentState === 'home }"
                    ui-sref="home">Home</li>
                <li ng-class="{ 'active': $ctrl.currentState === 'about }"
                    ui-sref="about">About</li>`;
  bindings = {
    stateName: '<'
  };
  controller = NavController;
}  

class NavController {
  $onChanges = (changesObj) => {
    if (changesObj.stateName.currentValue !== changesObj.stateName.previousValue) {
      this.currentState = changesObj.stateName.currentValue;
    }
  } 
}
```

Now this works, I'm just not sure how I feel about passing state via a binding. I guess what I'm asking is if there's a better way to do this – a more elegant solution perhaps?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just curious ... why don't you want to pass it via binding?

Comment: @ExplosionPills No reason. I just haven't passed state down before, so just questioning if this is the correct approach.

Comment: _"Any help is appreciated"_ Assigning `stateName` to another property and listen to changes makes no sense for this example. Neither does `Nav` being a class instead of an object. Moreover the question is tagged as "ecmascript-6", but  class properties are not supported in ES6.

Answer (score 0):

As you are basically listening on changes of $state.current.name, you could also listen directly on state change events.

I did a similar thing for a breadcrumb navigation but using the new transition hooks of ui-router: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/feature-1.0/. Transition hooks have the advantage that they eliminate the need to watch a variable or an event as they are called by the router once a transition is happening.

Or you could just cut out the middle man and directly consume $state within your component.

Answer (score 0):

There are few options -

1. If this component is supposed to be used for different dynamic navigation solutions - your solution is fine.
2. You can add 1 service in your application responsible for the state management - instead of working directly with the $state - and add a bunch of logic related to it. There isn't much advantage to hide it from your navigation control so you can just inject it to your controller and therefor avoid the binding. UT will also be simple because you can mock this service with no problem.

Comment: If I'm not passing the state via the binding, how can I listen for state changes inside the component? Is there a way to avoid `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', ...)`?

Comment: You can broadcast your custom event from the service, but thats more or less the same. Another option is to add a function on your controller returning the current state and bind your ngclass to it. The only pittfall here is to make sure a digest is activated when the state is changed, im pretty sure $state activates scope apply on the root scope when state changes